# If X is compatible with Y, what is Y in relation to X?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have something X that is compatible with something else, Y. So it is correct to say that "X is compatible with Y". Is there a word <word> such that this statement is equivalent to "Y is <word> with X"?

More generally, is there a standard way to convert a word <w> into a word <w2> such that "X is <w> to Y" is equivalent to "Y is <w2> to X"?

Comment: What is the context? What are X and Y? In some contexts if X is compatible with Y, then Y is compatible with X, but that doesn't always make sense.

Comment: @StuartF Basically, I have a certain mathematical structure, and for that structure there can be orders that are compatible with it, as in, it becomes another specific kind of structure when they are compatible.

Comment: Very generally “Y works with X.”

Comment: The simple answer here is "No".

Comment: Are you looking for the technical mathematical term? Is the relation 'compatible' reflexive? Are you looking for the word for the particular relation or for the class of all relations that are the 'other' direction? Answering these questions by editing will help future answerers. Also, you may want to ask on [math.SE] if this is about technical terminology.

Comment: @Mitch This technical term is a new one used by me and few other people in this context, so it is not a standard term. I asked this question to get an idea of what term to use for the converse relation.

Comment: If you're using _compatible_ for a mathematical relation, it ought to be commutative, because _compatible_ is commutative in its usual sense. If A is compatible with B, then B is compatible with A.

Comment: @Carlaonlyprovestrivialprop "This technical term is a new one used by me" - Which technical term? Is 'compatible' the new one? If not, can you tell us this new one you are using?

Comment: If your use of *compatible* carries a particular connotation that is not symmetric, it would help your question to spell that out. For example, if you restricted your definition of *compatible* to only mean *can eat*, then you could say *"Omnivores are compatible with carrots"* but not vice versa.

Comment: If there is an asymmetrical relationship, compatible might not be the best word. A fairly standard way to answer the w/w2 question is *subW* and *superW*: X is a superset of Y, Y is a subset of X. Also, pay careful attention to the preposition. If Proposition X is compatible with rule Y, then there is no special relationship from Y to X, but there may be one for your context, like Rule Y encompasses Proposition X. In the end, we'd need more details. English, btw, isn't generally regarded as the best language for expressing mathematical concepts.

Comment: The diversity and reflectiveness of the comments persuade that this is a good question about the meaning and usage of compatible, albeit it in various contexts.  Leave open.

Comment: (Allowing for multiple copies of individual elements within sets) a binary relation ⋆ defined on a set X is said to be **symmetric** if and only if for all elements in that set X a ⋆ b ⇔  b ⋆ a For instance, a = b ⇔ b = a; equality is a symmetric relation. // > is of course non-symmetric. a > b is incompatible with b > a.

Comment: *Receptive.* But that's biology.

Comment: What could possibly be the 'details of clarity' that those who voted to close this question think it is missing? The question is far more precise than most questions that appear on this site.  If one believes that there is no word that fits this definition or that different words may fit it, depending on the context, one should say that in an answer; these are not reasons for closing the question.

Comment: Are "forward compatibility" and "backward compatibility" relevant here?

Answer (score 2):

Compatibility is a symmetric relationship. If X is compatible with Y, then it follows, as a matter of logic, that Y is compatible with X. There is no need for a word other than *compatible* to express the latter (setting aside the considerations of pragmatics that will be addressed below). Or we can just say that X and Y are compatible, which makes the symmetric character of the relationship more visible.

If one is unclear about the symmetric character of compatibility, it may help to reflect on what compatibility is. To say that X is compatible with Y means that X and Y can be together without their being together producing significant clashes. (What precisely it is for X and Y to be together and what the nature of the relevant clashes is will depend on what X and Y are.) If X is incompatible with Y, then it is impossible for the two to be together, without significant clashes. As being together is a symmetric relationship, so is compatibility which is defined in terms of being together.

If all this is perfectly clear, why might there still be a perception that compatibility is not symmetric? This is, because as a matter of pragmatics, we are more likely to say that X is compatible with Y, rather than that Y is compatible with X, if we taking Y as given, and considering X as a possible addition to Y. Asking whether X is compatible with Y (rather than the other way round) conversationally implicates that, if they turn out to be incompatible, we'll sacrifice X, because we are committed to Y. That makes *compatible with* asymmetric in actual use, even though its definition makes it symmetric.

Now, if X is compatible with Y, what term should one use for the relation that Y has to X, if we want to take into account these considerations of pragmatics? There may not be a single word for that, but if one is allowed to help oneself to *can*, one might, depending on what X and Y are, be able to say that Y can accept/admit/accommodate/assimilate/absorb/incorporate X.

Incidentally, I am not clear as to whether this answer is compatible with the answers already posted. Some statements in them seem to go in the same direction as this one, but they also contain material that is problematic and the relevance of which is not obvious.

Comment: Now you've got me wondering about differences between a *symmetric* relationship and a *symmetric**al*** one. I **think** math more often uses the term *symmetric relationships*, while *symmetric**al** relationships* is used to denote a "balanced and equitable dynamic between individuals or entities". But I may be wrong.

Comment: By default, compatibilty is strongly non-symmetrical. That's why you *always* have to lexically specify the symmetric cases with such terms as "mutually compatible" or "compatible with each other"

Comment: @tchrist, now you've got me wondering. I have always assumed, without giving it any thought, that the choice between *symmetric* and *symmetrical* is a matter of individual preference, with no impact on meaning, but now that I pause to think about it, yes, you are right that *symmetric* heavily dominates the use in mathematics/logic (although *symmetrical* can occasionally be found in these contexts). It could, I guess, be a matter for another question to explore whether that is of any significance. To be on the safe side, I have changed *symmetrical* to *symmetric* throughout the answer.

Comment: @PhilSweet, I am not sure that I fully understand your answer, but it seems to me that what it says is similar to what is in the third paragraph of this answer, except for my treating that as a matter of pragmatics, and as something that is usually, but always, the case.

Answer (score 1):

From your username/profile picture I assume you are already familiar with binary relations, but I wanted to provide a more mathematically-inclined answer for others who come across this question.

A binary relation that adheres to the property "X relates to Y" ⇔ "Y relates to X" is called a [symmetric relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_relation). For those that are seeing this sort of thing for the first time, this means that if we know that one of these is true, then we automatically know the other one to be true as well.

As @Tuffy and commenters are right to note, for practical English use, it might not necessarily be the case that "compatible" is a symmetric relation. (E.g. in a one-sided romantic relationship, Person A might be "compatible" with Person B, but not vice versa.)

However, from your question I gather that you are less interested in the specifics of the term "compatible", and more interested in the 'structure-reversing' transformation piece. To the best of my knowledge there is not a general term popular in mathematics that can do this. I would suggest referring to it as the "symmetric statement", given the ubiquity in mathematics of the term symmetry for relations. (Alternatively, the "symmetric relationship" would also work in context, but this might be more prone to causing confusion given that it is already a well-defined term, as stated above.)

You might also be interested in using the term ["converse relation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Converse_relation). (Notably, a relation is symmetric iff it is equal to its converse.) However, this may also suffer from the same issue where the reader may confuse it as a reference to the relation in general, rather than the relationship between two specific elements.

Comment: Also worth noting is that the "X = Y and Y=Z, then X=Z" property in @Tuffy's answer is not always true in maths. This specific property is called [transitivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation). A relation that is symmetric, transitive, and [reflexive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_relation) (meaning that every element relates to itself), is called an equivalence relation. (Because it acts a lot like the equals sign!)

Comment: Compatibility is indeed a symmetrical relationship, and that should be the end of the answer. It is not clear why one would want to limit that to mathematical contexts. How could compatibility fail to be symmetrical in an everyday context? The answer mentions compatibility in romantic relationships, but it is not clear how that sort of compatibility would fail to be symmetrical either.

Answer (score 0):

As comments have suggested, you really need to provide a context.

In logic, if X **implies** Y, then **not-Y** implies not-X.  In other words, if Y is false, then X must be false.  The relationship between X and Y is one of *logical entailment*.

But compatibility is much trickier.  Take two people X and Y.  They live together.  They get along well.  There are no serious differences of behaviour, habits or taste.  It is not, for example, the case that one is obsessively tidy while the other treats the house like a slum and has disgusting habits.  They are in this and other respects 'compatible'.

It is usually assumed that compatibility is a binary quality:  If X is compatible, then surely X **and ** Y are **mutually** compatible.  So Y must be compatible with X.  Compatibility is  a little bit like equality.  If X= (is compatible with) Y, then Y= (is compatible with) X.

It works up to a point with two but not with more than that.  If X = Y and Y=Z, then X=Z.  This is true in maths but not in social relationships.  Just because John is compatible with Charles and Charles is compatible with Mary we cannot conclude that John is compatible with Mary.

Answer (score 0):

*Compatible* is most commonly used with strongly non-symmetric relations. So the "Y" is your example is typically an unconditional fact, and the "X" is some optional thing under consideration. In this situation X is *compatible* with Y and Y is *amenable* to X. This set of decisions is compatible with the established strategy. The strategy is amenable to this set of decisions.

> This study argues that relationship marketing offers a strategy amenable to nonprofits interested in donor relations.
> https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0892059194703736

This is the same as saying *Nonprofits interested in donor relations are compatible with a relationship marketing strategy.*

> This protocol provides a strategy amenable to the study of other organelles, including lysosomes, mitochondria, yolk vesicles, and the ER, and for tracking the motion of individual LDs along microtubules.
> https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/34958089/

This is the same as *The study of other organelles, including ..., is compatible with this protocol.*